# ffmpeg does not draw text

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

hope one of you can tell me why this ffmpeg command of mine does not draw the desired text. the produced video doesn't have it. here you go:

> ffmpeg -f image2 -thread_queue_size 64 -framerate 15.1 -i /home/michael-heuberger/binarykitchen/code/videomail.io/var/local/tmp/clients/videomail.io/11e6-723f-d0aa0bd0-aa9b-f7da27da678f/frames/%d.webp -y -an -vcodec libvpx -filter:v drawtext=fontfile=/home/michael-heuberger/binarykitchen/code/videomail.io/src/assets/fonts/Varela-Regular.ttf:text=www.videomail.io:fontsize=180:fontcolor=white:x=150:y=150:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=2 -vf scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2 -crf 12 -deadline realtime -cpu-used 4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -loglevel warning -movflags +faststart /home/michael-heuberger/binarykitchen/code/videomail.io/var/local/tmp/clients/videomail.io/11e6-723f-d0aa0bd0-aa9b-f7da27da678f/videomail_preview.webm

the crucial part is this video filter:

> -filter:v drawtext=fontfile=/home/michael-heuberger/binarykitchen/code/videomail.io/src/assets/fonts/Varela-Regular.ttf:text=www.videomail.io:fontsize=180:fontcolor=white:x=150:y=150:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=2

does it seem correct to you? if so, then why am i not seeing any text in the videomail_preview.webm video file?

using ffmpeg v2.8.6 here with --enable-libfreetype, --enable-libfontconfig and --enable-libfribidi enabled.

furthermore, the above command has been produced with fluent-ffmpeg.

so, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine all filters into a single graph, so

```
-filter:v drawtext=fontfile=/home/michael-heuberger/binarykitchen/code/videomail.io/src/assets/fonts/Varela-Regular.ttf:text=www.videomail.io:fontsize=180:fontcolor=white:x=150:y=150:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=2 -vf scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2
```

becomes

```
-filter:v drawtext=fontfile=/home/michael-heuberger/binarykitchen/code/videomail.io/src/assets/fonts/Varela-Regular.ttf:text=www.videomail.io:fontsize=180:fontcolor=white:x=150:y=150:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=2,scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2
```